# Laravel | three fields combination Valdiation

Tags: laravel

How to do a 3 fields combination validation?
I have this table `merchant_product`, the table has 4 columns :

- id
- merchant_id
- product_id
- branch_id

I don't want the same row duplicated like this when storing data.
Example :

| id | merhcant_id | product_id | branch_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I tried this approach but it seems not to work.

Here is my sample validation method :

```
$rules = [
            'product_id' => ['required','unique:merchant_product,product_id,NULL,id,merchant_id,'.Auth::id()', new Varchar],
            'merchant_id' => [new Varchar],
            'branch_id' => ['required','unique:merchant_product,branch_id,NULL,id,merchant_id,'.Auth::id()', new Varchar],
        ];
```

Comment: You can use `groupBy()` method on your query to prevent duplicate

Comment: @EsTeAa I'm storing a data from an input.

Comment: Edit and add your current validation method

Comment: @EsTeAa, Hi see my method.

Comment: just use firstOrCreate() on insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Rule::unique](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique) to validate both column together :

```
'product_id' => [
   'required',
    Rule::unique('merchant_product')->where(function ($query) use($request) {
       return $query->where('product_id', $request->product_id)
       ->where('branch_id', $request->branch_id);
    }),
],
```

Don't forget to add `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;` on the top

Answer (score 1):

Use `firstOrCreate()`

```
MerchantProduct::firstOrCreate([
    'product_id' => $productId, 
    'merchant_id' => $merchantId, 
    'branch_id' => $brandId
]);
```

This will stop any duplicate record being created, using all 3 columns without doing extra processing with rules.

See the following article for usage:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models